# Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Cannot access memory at address . What is the reason for getting this error

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

I am trying to compile and debug my code, runs on gcc 4.8.1 and using gdb version 7.5.1.

I am not sure what is causing this error, I cannot set a breakpoint or use start on gdb, all of them give the same (similar) error: 
`Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Cannot access memory at address 0xe0b01c`

I saw this answer [gdb error in re-settings breakpoint (cannot access memory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553527/gdb-error-in-re-settings-breakpoint-cannot-access-memory), but i am not using `-fPIE`, I am using `-fPIC` though, and 7.7.1 has same issue.

Is this issue due to gdb/gcc version or some flags? I am using: `-g -std=c++1 -D__GCC_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__=1`

Answer (score 0):

> Is this issue due to gdb/gcc version or some flags?

You didn't say whether you are setting breakpoint in the main executable, or in a shared library. The address: `0xe0b01c` looks like it came from a shared library or a PIE executable.

In any case, GCC version has *nothing* to do with this, but your GDB is quite old.

The standard solution is to use `(gdb) start`, then `enable` to re-enable the breakpoint (by the time you stop on `main`, the PIE executable and all directly-linked shared libraries have been relocated to their final addresses).

Comment: I did try running (gdb) start , which puts a temporary breakpoint and never hits it.    Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0xe0a982: file main.cc, line 106     Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Cannot access memory at address 0xe0a960 . None of the breakpoints i set hit .