# When I try to debug my program with gdb through pwntools, gdb insert a breakpoint at 0xXXX address

Tags: gdb, aslr, pwntools

When I try to debug my program with gdb through pwntools, gdb insert a breakpoint at 0xc0f address.

This address corresponds to the beginning of my program without the randomized part.

Below, my python script with pwntools:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pwn import *

p = gdb.debug('./lab6A','''
break main
continue <= I forgot to write this command in my first post.
''')
```

And a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

Comment: What version of GDB are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554339/50617 is probably relevant.

Comment: I use GNU gdb (Debian 8.3-1) 8.3. It is the last version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved after a big upgrade.

Before this, I reinstall gdb through apt-get.

Comment: In my script. Don't forget the continue or you will be getting some problem...